# Animation options ambigious without more context

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a hide function, which is hiding a specific view. however i keep getting following error: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context". What kind of more context do i need to provide?

```
func hide(toFrame:CGRect, delay:NSTimeInterval) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationSettings.duration,
        delay: delay,
        usingSpringWithDamping: animationSettings.damping,
        initialSpringVelocity: animationSettings.velocity,
        options: (.BeginFromCurrentState | .AllowUserInteraction),
        animations:{
            self.frame = self.offScreenFrame
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            self.delegate!.didNotifyFinishedAnimation(true)
            self.canNotify = true
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewAnimationOptions` is `OptionSetType` which is able to set syntax to define the options. Therefore, above codes need to be changed the options from `(.BeginFromCurrentState | .AllowUserInteraction)` to `[.BeginFromCurrentState, .AllowUserInteraction]`.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(animationSettings.duration,
    delay: delay,
    usingSpringWithDamping: animationSettings.damping,
    initialSpringVelocity: animationSettings.velocity,
    options: [.BeginFromCurrentState, .AllowUserInteraction],
    animations:{
        self.frame = self.offScreenFrame
    }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in
        self.delegate!.didNotifyFinishedAnimation(true)
        self.canNotify = true
    }
)
```